# Finding local min or max points for dirichlet if they exist.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$D(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\ x \in\mathbb Q\\
0 & \text{if}\ x \notin\mathbb Q
\end{cases}
$$
I have to somehow prove that for $\forall x, x_0 \in D$, $f(x)\le f(x_0)$ or $f(x)\ge f(x_0)$.

I know the function isn't continuous anywhere, but where I'm confused is whether or not the function is differentiable, and whether or not it could have local max or min values

$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ gives me $\frac00$.

Comment: Hint 1. What value can $D(x_0)$ be for any chosen $x_0$? Hint 2. What value can $D(x)$ be for any $x\ne x_0$? ...and for $x=x_0$...?

Comment: How can $x \in D$? $D$ is a function, not a set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if it doesn't matter whether or not it's differentiable.

For every $x_0$ in Q, $D(x_0)= 1$, and let $x_1 \in Q$. then $D(x_1)$=0.

Therefore, $D(x_0)\gt$ $D(x_1)$, therefore every $x_0$ we take is a local maximum, and it's the same for $D(x_0)\lt$ $D(x_1)$, where every $x_1$ will be a local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

A function doesn't have to be differentiable to have (local) minimum/maximum values. As differentiability at a point implies continuity at that point, the fact the the function isn't continuous anywhere shows that it can't be differentiable anywhere.

As written the condition doesn't make much sense, I assume that what you have to show is
$$
\forall x_0\in\mathbb R: 
(\forall x\in\mathbb R: f(x)\leq f(x_0))\lor
(\forall x\in\mathbb R: f(x)\geq f(x_0))
$$

If that is the case, you could consider the possible values of $f(x_0)$ and show the statement for all of the possible values independently.